# Can't convert timestamp to datetime using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm struggling to make use of the datetime function in Pandas, I'm ultimately trying to plot timestamp with row entries from my DataFrame.
I'm working with the following timestamp format:
`[23/Sep/2013:13:02:47+0200]`

Can someone help me with the code required to convert that format of timestamp to a datetime object, so I can then plot my graph of Timestamp against row entries, the aim is to have the attacks seen above correlated with the time of occurrence.

I'm currently getting `ParserError` with following code:

```
av3["Timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(av3["Timestamp"])
```

Error:

```
ParserError: Unknown string format: [23/Sep/2013:13:02:47+0200] present at position 0
```

Answer (score 0):

For custom datetime formats, specify the datetime format using the *format* argument in the `pandas.to_datetime()` function. For more details see [API Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).

```python
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
  "Timestamp": ["23/Sep/2013:13:02:47+0200"]
})

df["Timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"], format='%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S%z')

print(df["Timestamp"])
```

**Output:**

```
0   2013-09-23 13:02:47+02:00
Name: Timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC+02:00]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the string to get a `datetime` type. Read the documentation to understand the format string: [strftime() and strptime() Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

```
from datetime import datetime

date_string = "23/Sep/2013:13:02:47+0200"
format_string = "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S%z"
dt = datetime.strptime(date_string, format_string)

print(dt)
```

Output:

```
2013-09-23 13:02:47+02:00
```